# 403 Error using redmine_s3 plugin on Heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am running Redmine (1.2-stable branch from http://github.com/edavis10/redmine) on Heroku and want to use the redmine_s3 plugin (https://github.com/tigrish/redmine_s3) to store the assets on S3.

I used this guide for the setup: http://blog.firsthand.ca/2010/10/installing-redmine-on-heroku-with-s3.html

It works great locally, when I start Redmine (in production enivonment) it creates the configured bucket and stores any assets I upload in there.

But when I try to run it on Redmine it crashes on the first request to Heroku

```
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2303:in `error!': 403 "Forbidden" (Net::HTTPServerException)
from /app/vendor/plugins/redmine_r3/lib/S3.rb:306:in `block in make_request'
from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
from /app/vendor/plugins/redmine_r3/lib/S3.rb:281:in `make_request'
from /app/vendor/plugins/redmine_r3/lib/S3.rb:157:in `create_bucket'
from /app/vendor/plugins/redmine_r3/lib/redmine_s3/connection.rb:57:in `create_bucket'
from /app/vendor/plugins/redmine_r3/init.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

The offending line is here: https://github.com/tigrish/redmine_s3/blob/master/lib/S3.rb#L306

I double and triple checked, the configuration on Heroku and my local machine (S3 credentials, bucket name, etc.) is exactly the same.
I tried different bucket names and S3 credentials, still the same error.
Redmine itself (without the redmine_s3 plugin) works just great in Heroku.
Just as soon as I add the plugin... boom!

I suspect that the request from Heroku to S3 has some weird headers or other properties that make S3 reject the request.

Can anyone confirm or deny this?
I would be happy about any ideas on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it actually was an issue with Ruby 1.9.2. As soon as I downgraded to 1.8.7, it started working! :) Thanks to Jack Chu in the comments to Eric Davies for bringing me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

In which region is there your bucket? Try to use a bucket located in US Standard.

I had same trouble. First, I used a bucket that is located in Tokyo and i got same error message.
I checked response code and body. Response code was 409 Conflict. Error message was below.

```
BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou
Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.
```

I think this error means that redmine_s3 will try to create a bucket that has the bucket name you designated in US Standard. However there is a bucket that has same name in other region already. So you will get a error.

Comment: Yuki, thanks for your answer! I tried creating the bucket myself instead of letting redmine_s3 create it but I got the same error. I also tried creating the bucket in different regions and chose long bucket names that were guaranteed unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [fork of the plugin](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine_s3), I seem to remember a problem like that last year. It might be trying to create the bucket for the test environment, which if you didn't define on Heroku then it would fail ([potential fix](https://github.com/edavis10/redmine_s3/commit/8df30bb0607341d6f674fe63fa79c1e469a4cfc3)).

Comment: Thanks, Eric, but as you see in my question, I am already using your fork. :) Why would Redmine run in test env on Heroku?

Comment: I actually think it might be a Ruby 1.9.2 issue. I'm using Redmine on Heroku with this plugin (on ruby 1.8.7) and it works fine. I've been trying to convert my app to ChiliProject, which is a fork of Redmine, but I get 403's on the Heroku Cedar stack, which is 1.9.2.